# Where the he** does this left-over torx-screw come from?

Tags: renault, fastener, k7m

Renault Sandero K7m, 1.6 8v

Following a recent timing-belt change, I have put everything back together, fired her up and everything is peachy(so far).

But I have a left over bolt.

It is a torx bolt/screw, and I can't remember where it came from.

It was around the time I removed the plastic wheel arch. That plastic wheel arch is a bit of an enigma. Not least because there were a few connectors/bolts/screws missing when I started. Renault appears to have gone with the 'variety is the spice of life' approach when designing for the fasteners.

It is not the locking-pin bolt, which is also a torx bolt but much shorter, and it is not the top-bolt for the bracket covering the crank-pulley(that's also a torx-bolt).

Edit: [image: for scale and general identification]

Comment: Picture or it didn't happen :o)

Comment: That narrows it down to a few thousand possibilities..

Comment: Apologies... guess when I posted this question I was still a bit excited from the engine not having being destroyed. I have added a picture for scale and identification.

Comment: If this was an 91 Chevy Camaro, I could tell you one of 30 places this could go ... I don't know enough about Renault to tell you where it goes. Best suggestion? Check around your engine and see where it *might* go. Pics help big time though.

Comment: I have a feeling it came out with the very first plastic access panel after I took the wheel off.

The plastic wheel arch itself was still in place. It may be a good idea to ask the renault dealer.

Comment: Then take the wheel off and have a look. After a garage job I found one bolt lying on the plastic "wiper tray" and I took the car back. The mechanic soon found where is was missing, and so could I have done if I had looked. If Renault uses lots of different fasteners that should narrow down the search.

Comment: You can spell the word **hell** in full on here. It's 2023, not 1823.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Just goofing around ;-)